# Blob object javascript duplicate their value

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, download

I have problems downloading files from my application using ajax. This is the situation.

I have a **Ajax POST** call to my download URL. This ajax length is **3.3MB** (the file that I am returning size). Anyway, I double checked this url return my file when I access it from browser in the correct way.

To download it, I use this code in the success:

```
success: function(data){
var blob=new Blob([data]);
var link=document.createElement('a');
link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download=[[${videoInfo.title}]]+".mp3";
link.click();
link.remove();
},
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/I24touY.png]

If I print `blob.size` o see the downloaded file sie, it is from **6.6MB** (double of real size) and I can't play the mp3 file because is corrupted. If I enter my url directly in browser, I can download the correct version of file. This is my server code:

```
Path path = Paths.get(target.getAbsolutePath());
result = Files.readAllBytes(path);

ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentLengthLong(result.length);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
        "attachment; filename='" + downloadInfo.getVideo().getTitle() + ".mp3'");
response.setContentType(MP3_MIME_TYPE);
sos.write(result);
sos.flush();
```

It looks like if there are anything wrong with the Blob object conversion, but it's the first time that I work with this object and maybe I am missing something.

Any helps with this?

Comment: you may specify the type of the file when instanciating the  Blob object: var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'audio/x-mpeg'});

Comment: in your case this should be 'audio/mp3'

Comment: Thanks Marouen, but the generated file is corrupted anyway :(

Comment: did u found any solution for your issue?

Comment: No for the moment, I change the way that I make the download